# navbar is not fluid as well its no inside in container

Tags: css

```
Here is my html code!
 <div id="container"> 
        <div class="main-header">
            <img  id="logo" src="images/1.jpg" alt="vector"> </img> 
<!-- using another div inside of it navigation bar and logo-->
            <nav class="main-nav">
            <!-- remember you have to have floating elements
            inside of non floating object like main-nav -->
                <ul> 
                    <li><a class ="active "href="#"> Home </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Services </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Colaborate </a></li>       
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
     </div>
Here is my css code!
     #container{
       width:80%; /* again using 80% just to make fluid other wise it could 
       be 960 px;  --*/
       margin:0 auto;
         background-color:#2EFEF7;
        overflow:auto;
        clear:both;

}

 #logo{
    width:20%;
    margin:10px 0px;    
 }
 .main-nav{
    background-color:#882433;
    height:30px;
   border-radius:5px;
   border:px solid #c13046;
   color:white; 
  }
      .main-nav ul{
      list-style:none;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       display:inline-block;    

      }
    .main-nav li{
    color:#ffffff;
    float:left;
    margin-left:3px;

   }
    .main-nav li a{
    color:#ffffff;
    /* this is used to escape from scroll bar*/
   padding:10px 20px;
   height:20px;
   display:inline-block;

}
    .main-nav li a:hover{
   background-color:#efeadd;
    color:#666666;
     border-radius:5px;

}
.main-nav li a:active{
   background-color:#efeadd;
   color:#666666;
   border-radius:5px;
```

}

i am having container and all of my nav elements are inside of it but problem is container is not wrapping navigation bar. 2nd: problem this navigation bar is not fluid means it is not responsive as its not working when i scale down my browser please be specific on my question because i am beginner.

Comment: you forgot your css code

Comment: Nav bar is wrapping inside container, its working fine for me. I think you forgot to post your css code.

Answer (score 0):

First, img is self closing tag, so there shouldn't be < /img>
Second, you need

```
img {max-width:100%; height: auto}
```

in your css